# Two different text values not displayed correctly in same HStack when using Menu structures

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a problem when displaying month name + year number in Menu structure labels

There is an HStack

```
HStack(spacing: 5) {
    Menu {
        ForEach(monthSymbols, id: \.self) { monthSymbol in
            Button(monthSymbol, action: {
                for (index, symbol) in monthSymbols.enumerated() where symbol == monthSymbol {
                    anyDateComponentChanged = true
                    pickedMonthNumber = index + 1
                }
            })
        }
    } label: {
        Text("\(pickedMonthName),")
            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
    }
    
    Menu {
        ForEach(yearsRange, id: \.self) { yearNumber in
            Button(String(yearNumber), action: {
                anyDateComponentChanged = true
                pickedYearNumber = yearNumber
            })
        }
    } label: {
        Text(String(pickedYearNumber))
            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
    }
}
```

That displays both month name and year number which both are Menu structures that let user choose corresponding month and year. There is problem when month name or year number is too long - then it collapses with `...` just like this:

[image]

I tried using `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)` modifier to both text labels and problem was fixed however there was new one - when month name was too long, it overlayed the year number:

[image]

When either month menu label or year menu label is clicked and month or year choosing appears the text automatically gets it's correct space:

[image]

I know that the solution would be to put month name and year number in one string however then I would not be able to use two different menus. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually I needed to combine `.fixedSize` on `HStack` and custom `.frame` modifier on both `Text` structures resulting in:

```
HStack(spacing: 5) {
                Menu {
                    ForEach(monthSymbols, id: \.self) { monthSymbol in
                        Button(monthSymbol, action: {
                            for (index, symbol) in monthSymbols.enumerated() where symbol == monthSymbol {
                                anyDateComponentChanged = true
                                pickedMonthNumber = index + 1
                            }
                        })
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("\(pickedMonthName),")
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        .frame(minWidth: 130,
                               maxWidth: .infinity,
                               alignment: .trailing)
                }
                
                Menu {
                    ForEach(yearsRange, id: \.self) { yearNumber in
                        Button(String(yearNumber), action: {
                            anyDateComponentChanged = true
                            pickedYearNumber = yearNumber
                        })
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text(String(pickedYearNumber))
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        .frame(minWidth: 70,
                               maxWidth: .infinity,
                               alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
            .fixedSize()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `HStack` is not sizing properly.

Add `.fixedSize()` to the `HStack()` that contains your two `Text` labels and keep the `.fixedSize()` modifiers you added to the `Text` labels.