# How to avoid animation of HStack size changes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to figure out how to suppress the animation of `HStack` size changes.  Here is a stand-alone example which is a simplified version of my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73500660/1630618).
This date picker uses 2 menus to allow for the selection of month and year.  Just tap either to pop up a menu and select the new value.

[image: app running in playground]

I have added `.animation(nil)` to suppress the animations resulting from the size changes of the `HStack` when the month changes.  Unfortunately this is now deprecated in IOS 15.

[image: error message on Swift Playgrounds]

If you remove the `.animation(nil)` you will see the undesired animation.

---

### Things I have tried:

1. I tried adding a value to the animation line:
   `animation(nil, value: pickedMonth)`
2. I tried wrapping the setting of the `pickedMonth` in `withAnimation(nil) { }`

Neither of these stopped the animation.

How should this be done in iOS 15 and later?

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    let years = 1990..<2025
    @State private var pickedMonth = "May"
    @State private var pickedYear = 2022
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 5) {
            Menu {
                ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
                    Button(month) {
                        // withAnimation(nil) {
                            pickedMonth = month
                        // }
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("\(pickedMonth),")
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            
            Menu {
                ForEach(years, id: \.self) { year in
                    Button(String(year)) {
                        pickedYear = year
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text(String(pickedYear))
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
        }
        .fixedSize()
        .animation(nil)
        //.animation(nil, value: pickedMonth)
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, since it got deprecated on iOS 15, you still have a good 2 years before it's removed. Secondly, I'm not sure if it's possible to disable normal behavior of iOS views.

Comment: @SotirisKaniras, iOS 15 is nearly a year old, so maybe just one year before it is removed.  I like to avoid all build warnings where possible.

Comment: To use different version of a modifier you can create your own view modifier that can include in its body the available tests. If iOS 15 or newer use new animation modifier  to content else use old animation modifier to content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me introduce you to my friend `Transaction`. Transactions allow you to intercept an already set animation and change it. The traditional way of using it is similar to `withAnimation` in which you enclose the animated value with `withTransaction()` closure. However, because you want the animation to be nil in a different view every time, you can use the `.transaction` view modifier form like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    let years = 1990..<2025
    @State private var pickedMonth = "May"
    @State private var pickedYear = 2022
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 5) {
            Menu {
                ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
                    Button(month) {
                            pickedMonth = month
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("\(pickedMonth),")
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            
            Menu {
                ForEach(years, id: \.self) { year in
                    Button(String(year)) {
                        pickedYear = year
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text(String(pickedYear))
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
        }
        .fixedSize()
        // place it here
        .transaction { hstackTransaction in // get the transaction
            hstackTransaction.animation = nil // modify the transaction's animation
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of the fact that `.animation()` compiles, it has serious issues which is why it is deprecated. I am not sure if `.animation(nil)` shares those issues, but you are right to want to purge it from your code.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks @Yrb.  I had found that adding `.id(UUID())` to the `HStack` suppressed the animation, but that is a hack and this is a much better approach.

Comment: The nice thing with this is it allows you to change Apple's default animations into whatever you want. You are specifying none, but you could animate it to jump around the screen a few times if you wanted...

Comment: I did in fact try that and had it loop forever.  Very cool!